# .htaccess rewrite rule killing me

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to write a rewrite rule for .htaccess. I think I'm pretty close, but I change one thing, and then I mess something else up. I'm not very savvy with .htaccess or regex, I could use some help.

Here's the logic I need.

I start with:

```
RewriteEngine on
```

I have a folder with subfolders in it. 
1) I need the folder and subfolders to be 403, so I did this and it worked:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

RewriteRule ^ - [R=403]
```

So far so good.

2) Inside the subfolders there are images, different sizes of the same image, but they don't all exist yet.
I have an image.original.png file.

If this file is requested directly and it does not exist, I need it to show 404. so I did:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^(.*)\.original\.png$

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^ - [R=404]
```

That seems to be working fine as well.
Here comes the part where I'm getting stuck.

if the image.original.png file is requested directly and it does exist, I want to show another file which would be image.png. If image.png doesn't exist it gets redirected to index.php which will generate image.png, save it for further use and display it.

So the whole point is, the user never gets to see image.original.png

Then there is the last part.
There are several variations of image.png which could be image.280.png image.420.png image.660.png image.880.png, you get the idea.

When any of these variations is requested, if they exist it should just serve them.

If they don't it should check for image.original.png and if it doesn't exist it should show 404.

If image.original.png exists then it should go to index.php where image.requestedvariation.png will be generated, saved for future use and served.

Here is what I got so far...

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

RewriteRule ^ - [R=403]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^(.*)\.original\.png$

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^ - [R=404]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^(.*)\.original\.png$

RewriteRule ^(.*)\.original\.png$ ./$1.png

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^(.*)\.(.*)\.png$

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^(.*)\.(.+)\.png$

RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(.+)\.png$ ./$1.original.png

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php
```

At some point along that mess I just got lost.

Please Help! :D
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you simplify the question? Are you getting an error, `I just got lost` isn't a lot to go on.

Comment: I sometimes get an error, sometimes it falls back to inedx.php when its not supposed to. The code above gets no error, but its not checking for item.original.png existance in order to see if it shows the variations.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I finally got it to work! :D

Here is the code: ( I added a bunch of variables to index.php for debugging but I guess they aren't really necessary )

```
#TURN REWRITEENGINE on
RewriteEngine on

#IF FILENAME IS DIRECTORY
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [R=403,L]

#IF FILENAME ENDS WITH .original.png AND FILENAME DOES NOT EXIST
#REDIRECT 404
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^(.*)\.original\.png$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]

#RULE 1
#IF FILENAME ENDS WITH .original.png 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^(.*)\.original\.png$
#AND FILE WITHOUT .original DOES NOT EXIST
RewriteCond ./%1.png !-f
#PIPE TO index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.original\.png$ index.php?rule=1&f=%{REQUEST_FILENAME}&r=./$1.png&r0=$0&r1=$1&r2=$2&r3=$3&r4=$4&r5=$5&r6=$6&r7=$7&r8=$8&r9=$9&c0=%0&c1=%1&c2=%2&c3=%3&c4=%4&c5=%5&c6=%6&c7=%7&c8=%8&c9=%9 [L]

#RULE 2
#IF FILENAME ENDS WITH .original.png 
#AND FILE WITHOUT .original DOES EXIST SINCE IT SKIPPED RULE 1
#REWRITE TO FILE WITHOUT .original
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^(.*)\.original\.png$
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.original\.png$ ./$1.png

#RULE 3
#IF FILENAME IS .png WITHOUT ANY SUFFIX
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^(.*)\.(.*)\.png$
#AND FILENAME IS .png
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^(.*)\.png$
#AND .original DOES exist
RewriteCond ./%1.original.png -f
#AND FILENAME WITHOUT SUFFIX DOES NOT EXIST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#PIPE TO index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.png$ index.php?rule=3&f=%{REQUEST_FILENAME}&r0=$0&r1=$1&r2=$2&r3=$3&r4=$4&r5=$5&r6=$6&r7=$7&r8=$8&r9=$9&c0=%0&c1=%1&c2=%2&c3=%3&c4=%4&c5=%5&c6=%6&c7=%7&c8=%8&c9=%9 [L]

#RULE 4
#IF FILENAME IS .png WITH SUFFIX
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^(.*)\.(.*)\.png$
#AND FILENAME DOES NOT EXIST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#PIPE TO index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.png$ index.php?rule=4&f=%{REQUEST_FILENAME}&r0=$0&r1=$1&r2=$2&r3=$3&r4=$4&r5=$5&r6=$6&r7=$7&r8=$8&r9=$9&c0=%0&c1=%1&c2=%2&c3=%3&c4=%4&c5=%5&c6=%6&c7=%7&c8=%8&c9=%9 [L]
```